# Docker Compose Connection Refused For Keycloak and Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, keycloak-connect

I am fairly new to docker. So I have a docker compose.yml file which helps me dockerize keycloak and a Spring boot Application. Here is my application-docker.yml file

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          MyRealm:
            client-id: myclient
            client-secret: mysecrete
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-url: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/myclient"
            scope:
              - openid
              - profile
              - email
              - roles
        provider:
          MyRealm:
            issuer-uri: "http://localhost:8090/realms/myRealm"
```

And here is my docker.yml file

```
  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.4
    command: ["start-dev","--import-realm"]
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL_HOST: keycloak-postgres
      KC_DB_URL_DATABASE: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: mypassword
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: mypassword
    ports:
      - "8090:8080"
    expose:
      - "8090"
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"
    depends_on:
      keycloak-postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - astro_network


  astro-orb:
    image: astromyllc/astro-orb:0.001
    container_name: astro-orb
    pull_policy: always
    ports:
      - "7013:7013"
    expose:
      - "7013"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"
    depends_on:
      keycloak:
        condition: service_healthy
      discovery-server:
        condition: service_healthy
      astro-api-gateway:
        condition: service_healthy
      zipkin:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - astro_network



networks:
  astro_network:
    driver: bridge
```

This works when I have keycloak running from docker and the spring boot application running from my IDE.
But after deploying both to docker I get this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authorizedClientService': Error creating bean with name 'authorizedClientService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'authorizedClientService' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception with message: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://localhost:8090/realms/ShootingStar"
.
.
.
.
... 47 common frames omitted
2024-01-22 01:13:14 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://localhost:8090/realms/ShootingStar"
.
.
.
... 48 common frames omitted
2024-01-22 01:13:14 Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8090/realms/ShootingStar/.well-known/openid-configuration": Connection refused
```

how do I fix this please. Its been days now and I am not making any headway

I tried using the docker IP of the keycloak.
When I use the docker port (8080)  of keycloak, the spring app runs but I cants access it from the local browser.
I tried using the container name(ie keycloak) in he issuer-uri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When you specify `localhost` in your Spring Boot application's configuration, it tries to connect to itself (since within its container, `localhost` refers to the container itself, not your host machine). Instead, use the service name defined in the **Docker Compose** file (in your case, it seems to be `keycloak`) as the hostname.

- Update the issuer URI in your Spring Boot application's configuration to:

  ```yaml
  issuer-uri: "http://keycloak:8080/realms/myRealm"
  ```

  This change tells your application to connect to the `keycloak` service on the Docker internal network.

2. You've mapped the Keycloak port to `8090` on your host. This is correct for accessing Keycloak from your host browser. However, within the Docker network (between containers), you should use the internal port which Keycloak listens on, typically `8080`.
3. You have defined a custom network `astro_network`. Make sure all relevant services are attached to this network for them to communicate internally.

Comment: Thank you @Hien Hoang. Changing the issuer-uri to "http://keycloak:8080/realms/myRealm" works allowing the spring app container to start and run . But now its presenting a new challenge. 
Its unable to redirect to the keycloak SSO.
The valid redirect gives
http://keycloak:8080/realms/myRealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=myclient&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20roles&state=ZLScaJfpf-EtKqQvjTlz5Hcw2Kv1FiaJOZwjwuSKJ0o%3D&redirect_uri=http://localhost:7013/login/oauth2/code/myrealm&nonce=y47MLVbXHQfHKtWMrFYiVSUVcuguDGHrf7D-Zz4NPWU.
It is using 8080 not the 8090